# Installshield Limited Edition - Limitations

Tags: installshield, installshield-le

I am new to installshield with VS2013 Community Edition.  Just downloaded the Installshield Limited Edition to give a try. With this,  I am able to create a setup file and able to sign the setup.

My questions are

1. Is there any limitations on using LE(limited Edition)?
2. How long I can use the LE.  Any time limitation (trial period)?
3. Can I create a setup file and use it for production users?  Will it cause any problem?
4. What is difference between LE and Express\premier\professtional Editions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. There are quite a considerable amount of limitations in the limited edition. For an example.

- The user cannot add additional dialog screens apart from the given by default.
- Limitations when defining Custom Actions.
- The user only can define banners and main image to setup.
- All it can do is extract the given files, folder structures which are defined in the solution.
- There is no harm providing a basic output setup using Install Shield Limited Edition.
- There are no trial periods, user can continue using limited edition as long as they like. And can switch to professional, premium whenever they like.
- The differences between limited and other versions is, that the user can define custom actions, get user inputs to dialogs and add custom dialogs to the setup wizard.

I suggest you to have this extension (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d), which is the same windows installer plug in that allows you to work with as you were working in Visual Studio 2010 deployment project type.

(update on 24-02-2017)
Or if you like a little action, I suggest you to use [windows installer XML](http://wixtoolset.org/) extension.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also I see that limited edition you can not create application pool for IIS